# Limitar el tamaño de un informe en access al momento de imprimir

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

Estoy creando un informe dinámico, que debe imprimir la cantidad de artículos que yo desee vender por factura a cada cliente.
Access trabaja por defecto con un tamaño de hoja carta o formato A4 y el tamaño de los tickets del informe es diferente.

Mediante código, ¿es posible imprimir estos datos de manera dinámica, generando al mismo tiempo un formulario y su vista previa para imprimirla?

Imagen para aclarar:

[image: imagen]

Comment: ¿Por qué la imagen en inglés? Independientemente de eso, no me queda claro cuales a que se refiere esta pregutna. ¿Se trata de imprimir un registro por página o múltiples registros por página?

Comment: @Rubén disculpa, es que había hecho la pregunta en el sitio en ingles, y pues m dio pereza hacer dos imágenes en dos idiomas diferentes, ya lo solucione de la forma mas sencilla, en el chat te cuento

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pude solucionar este problema de una forma sencilla, sin usar código ni nada por el estilo.

la impresora que uso para las impresiones de recibos de estilo ticket, es una Epson TM-88V.

Bueno primero vamos a las configuraciones de la impresora, podemos hacerlo en el panel de control y buscamos los dispositivos etc. allí vamos a darle click derecho a el icono de la impresora, y posterior a esto, elegiremos la opción **Preferencias de la impresión** y nos aparece esta ventana de múltiples opciones, en donde iremos a opciones avanzadas

[image: imagen 1]

Luego presionamos ese botón que dice **Configuraciones avanzadas**, el cual nos pedirá permiso de administrador, le decimos que si, y nos aparecerá esta nueva ventana con mas opciones

[image: imagen 2]

Luego vamos a la opción **enviar código**, en donde veremos muchas opciones, las cuales, nos indican que tipo de información queremos enviarle a la impresora, entonces le daremos click a el boton **Editar**, y miraremos los códigos y su referente, así sabremos cuando podemos indicarle a la impresora, si es el final o el comienzo de la pagina

[image: imagen 3]

Luego de ver los códigos, elegimos el que nosotros vamos a indicarle a la impresora, en mi caso, elegi el `02`, este equivale a un asterisco.

[image: imagen 4]

Luego en su informe lo configuran y colocan los asteriscos que quieran, en mi caso puse una linea de asteriscos, y funciono perfecto.